# Diagonlisation of certain matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Why is it that the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & -3 & -1 \\ -3 & 5 & -1 \\ -3 & 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is diagonalisable, even though it has eigenvalues 1, 2, 2 (which are not all distinct) but $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$ is not, despite the fact that it too has two eigenvalues which are not distinct (in fact exactly the same eigenvalues: 1, 2, 2)?

Comment: There is a theorem that says that a matrix is diagonalizable (in a field $\mathbb{F}$) iff its *minimal polynomial* can be factored in $\mathbb{F}$, and has simple roots. Note that the minimal $\mu$ and characteristic polynomial $\chi$ are two different things: they have the same roots, but not necessarily with the same multiplicity: in general, $\mu\mid \chi$.

Comment: compute the null space of $A-2I$ for each matrix and see what happens.

Comment: cf difference between [geometric multiplicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Geometric_multiplicity) and [algebraic multiplicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Algebraic_multiplicity)

Comment: To expand anderstood idea, you have that a square matrix is diagonalizable if and only if any eigenvalue $\lambda$ has equal algebraic and geometric multiplicities.

Comment: For the eigenvalue of 2, can you find two independent eigenvectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $n \times n$ matrix (over $\mathbb{R}$ or any other field) is diagonalizable if the set of his eigenvector is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. So the matrix must have $n$ linearly independent eigenvector.

For $n=3$, if the matrix has an eigenvalue of multiplicity $2$ (as in your case), then we have two possibilities:

1) this ''double'' eigenvalue has two linearly independent eigenvector, and in this case we say that it has algebraic multiplicity $2$ and **geometric multiplicity** $2$ ( this means that the eigenvalue ''span'' a plane in $R^3$).

2) The ''double'' eigenvalue has only one eigenvector, and his geometric multiplicity is $1$ ( the eigenvalue ''span'' a straight line).

So, your first matrix has two distinct eigenvalues, one of them ( $\lambda=2$) of algebraic multiplicity 2, but has three linearly independent eigenvectors since $\lambda=2$ has geometric multiplicity $2$. So this matrix is diagonalisable.
For the second matrix you can see that the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda=2$ is $1$, so that there are not three linearly independent eigenvectors.